# Date(s) intersection in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have one table "leave" having the structure

```
id int autoincrement primary key,
leaveid int FOREIGN KEY,
startdate date,
enddate date,
noofleave float
```

I want to fetch the intersecting days for two or more leaveids, the result will be as shown below.

```
leaveid | startdate  | enddate    | noofleave 
 4      | 2016-01-18 | 2016-01-27 | 1
 8      | 2016-01-18 | 2016-01-22 | 1
 8      | 2016-01-24 | 2016-01-25 | 0.5
 8      | 2016-01-26 | 2016-01-27 | 0.5
```

Here I have only two inputs (`leaveid` 4 & 8). Using this i want to get the intersecting(overlapping) days as above for these leaveid's. how can i write the query ?

Comment: Please clarify your question with clearly marked sample input and output.  Do you want overlapping date ranges, or something else?